# How to redistribute live data coming from a application server to a series of clients

Tags: php, python, server

I have two application servers acting as clients that can be configured to send live events to a remote Web server using HTTP POST (the data is XML format). That is the only way the data can be exported.

Now I need that, the data received to be send from that "Web server" in the moment it was received to a series of other clients connected to the same "Web server", without the need for the clients to ask the server for any new data.

The so called "Web server" will listen to TCP port 80 for incoming HTTP requests from the first two clients and also listening to a different TCP port where multiple user clients are connecting to receive the live data originally coming from its clients connected to port 80.

[image: Connections diagram]
.

I was thinking to use PHP (or Python) to listen on two separated TCP ports for incoming connections.
One port, where it is receiving the XML data events from multiple clients (two at the moment) and send back a "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", then close the connection, and one port (**Raw socket**) where multiple persistent connections can receive the XML data events, without the need for those clients to ask the server if there is any new data available.

How can I create the server side to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Have you explored HTTP/2 Server Push? What have you tried so far or is this still just a thought experiment?

Comment: The data is dynamic and the connections with the right side clients must remain active, not as a HTTP connection which is closed after the server is answering the request. More as a WebSocket/Raw Socket (persistent bidirectional channel between the client and the server).

Comment: I've was thinking to use Apache and PHP to receive the data from left side clients and store it to MySQL, and again PHP to listen to incoming connections on a raw socket and deliver the data from the database to all incoming clients (right side). But I don't know how to do the second part :D and it seems complicated because there has to be a loop mechanism that has to query the database to see if there is any new data available, and if any push it to the right side clients

Comment: I understand the data is dynamic, but how often does it change? If you know the update interval, it may be easier and less stressful on the server in the middle to have the clients poll the data at regular intervals using ajax. For the (human) client in front of the screen the difference between getting data by pulling or having it pushed is irrelevant. Having said that, if your "middle" server could run Nginx you could try something like this: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/push_stream/ I'm sure there's an Apache way to do it too

Comment: The left side clients are videoconferencing servers which are sending live events about participants that are connecting/disconnecting, calls that are created/ended and this data is send as it is produced and should get to the operators as quick as possible. I'm building a videoconferencing management platform using APIs and live events that are real time data and I want to be able to use this data as it comes. When it will be finished I'll publish it on Internet for free. push_stream may work if the connection is persistent. I'll have to try. Thanks.